# How to include Bootstrap Android in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-bootstrap

I want to know if any one of you have tried to install the [boostrap android](http://www.androidbootstrap.com/) app on eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Bootstrap is a generate application template tool. That don't support eclipse. Support only Android Studio.